# When I use the \begin{thebibliography} command, I get it as a chapter. How can I get rid of that?

Tags: bibliographies, report

I want to include a reference list at the end of my report, but when I use the command `\begin{thebibliography}`, I get a heading which says "Chapter 1". Here is an example:

```
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
\begin{thebibliography}{10}
\bibitem{notes} John W. Dower {\em Readings compiled for History 21.479.} 1991.
\bibitem{impj}  The Japan Reader {\em Imperial Japan 1800-1945} 1973: Random House, N.Y.
\end{thebibliography}
```

The `\renewcommand{\bibname}{}` just removes the "Bibliography" title. On the top of the page it still says "Chapter 1" (because I use the `\chapter*{chaptername}` command). I know that the report class will define bibliography as a chapter, and the article class will define it as a section, but I am dependent on using the report class. Thanks in advance!!
[image: I want to get rid of "Kapittel 1" ("Chapter 1")]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Why do you want to have `bibname` empty?

Comment: By the way: `\em` is one of the outdated commands. You should use `\emph{...}` instead

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the `tocbibind` package. It will choose the correct style of chapter/section heading for the bibliography section.

```
\documentclass{report}


\usepackage{tocbibind}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
\begin{thebibliography}{10}
\bibitem{notes} John W. Dower {\emph{Readings compiled for History 21.479.}} 1991.
\bibitem{impj}  The Japan Reader {\emph{Imperial Japan 1800-1945}} 1973: Random House, N.Y.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In principle, `tocbibind` shouldn't be necessary at all if `\bibliography` would be used, but the whole document is only fragmented, so the question is unclear

Answer (score 1):

You can temporarily disable the `\chapter` functionality, porting it to whatever `\section` would do via

```
\let\chapter\section
```

If you need `\chapter` functionality after your bibliography, then it can also be restored:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

% Store \chapter functionality in \oldchapter
\let\oldchapter\chapter

\begin{document}

% Let \chapter act just like \section
\let\chapter\section
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
\begin{thebibliography}{10}
  \bibitem{notes} John W. Dower \emph{Readings compiled for History 21.479.} 1991.
  \bibitem{impj}  The Japan Reader \emph{Imperial Japan 1800-1945} 1973: Random House, N.Y.
\end{thebibliography}

%% Restore original \chapter functionality
%\let\chapter\oldchapter
\end{document}
```