# Should I cite using \begin{thebibliography} or \begin{filecontents*}

Tags: bibliographies

I am new to LaTeX and I need to create a list of references.

I browsed through this forum and couldn't find some uniform standard for doing references.

Many people are using, e.g, [How to reference properly when citations are grouped by sections](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/205077/how-to-reference-properly-when-citations-are-grouped-by-sections)

```
\begin{filecontents*}

@article{A1,
  keywords = {articles},
  title={First Paper},
  author={Green},
  journal={Journal 1}, 
  note={based on \cite{C2}},
  year={2014}
}
```

Others are using, e.g., [When I use the \begin{thebibliography} command, I get it as a chapter. How can I get rid of that?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/295527/when-i-use-the-beginthebibliography-command-i-get-it-as-a-chapter-how-can-i)

```
\begin{thebibliography}{10}
\bibitem{notes} John W. Dower {\emph{Readings compiled for History 21.479.}} 1991.
\bibitem{impj}  The Japan Reader {\emph{Imperial Japan 1800-1945}} 1973: Random House, N.Y.
\end{thebibliography}
```

What is the form of citation that someone new to LaTeX should use?

And based on what criteria would one choose one method of citation over the other?

Comment: the filecontents version is a bibtex `.bib` file normally that would be edited as a separate file, sometimes people put it in filecontents to make a single file example to post here but there is no advantage to doing that in a real document. bibtex will take a .bib file and generate a bibliography enviornment like the one you show, so the two methods are not so different.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, may be you didn't notice the second method that is a bibliography created be `\begin{thebibliography}` and not by using a `.bib` file. I would add that in the second method this kind of manual created method has the disadvantage thet you can't easy change its style by selecting another `.bst` (bibliography style) to customize your exported form `.bib` bibliography.

Comment: @koleygr but to latex it is the same thing, all bibtex does is generate a `thebibliography` enviornment for you. I agree the OP should start by using bibtex and a bib file

Comment: To comment on the question: the 'normal' way of creating a list of references (called 'bibliography') is to make a separate file with the references in it and run BibTeX or BibLaTeX on your document. See for example https://www.latex-tutorial.com/tutorials/bibtex/.

Comment: Ok @DavidCarlisle... Of course bibtex generates the `.bbl` that is like this ... I just wanted to add that by using `bibtex` you don't have to edit all your entries in order to change between usual styles of bibliography ... But of course (in some cases) even this way could be simpler if you don't know what to do with a complicated `.bst` file and/or you don't have the knowledge to change the bst file etc.

Answer (score 4):

For practical purposes the distinction that should be made is not between `thebibliography` on one side and `filecontents` on the other, but between `thebibliography` on one side and `.bib` files and BibTeX on the other.

In the bibliography context `filecontents` is usually only used to make example files self-contained and produce a `.bib` file for use with BibTeX. That is why you will find many mentions of it here, but in production use one would normally not use it. (I don't doubt that some people do, maybe because they find it more convenient, or maybe because they picked it up as a habit from various sites on the web.)

### Manual `thebibliography`

`thebibliography` is the manual way to produce bibliographies in citations. All LaTeX offers you here is basically a way to produce a list of labelled entries that can be referenced with `\cite`. `thebibliography` usually works like an `enumerate` list that uses `\bibitem[<optional label>]{<entry key>}` instead of `\item[<optional label>]` and automatically sets a `\label` that you can refer to with `\cite` (instead of `\ref`). Everything else is left to you. You have to write and format the entire entry, you have to sort the list, you have to assign labels if you don't want to use a numbered citation style.

```
\begin{thebibliography}{2}
\bibitem{notes} John W. Dower \emph{Readings compiled for History 21.479.} 1991.
\bibitem{impj}  The Japan Reader \emph{Imperial Japan 1800-1945} 1973: Random House, N.Y.
\end{thebibliography}
```

#### Pros

- The method is easy to get the hang of once you realise it is just a fancy `enumerate`.
- You have full control over all details of the formatting and sorting of the entries.
- No external programs are needed to compile the citations. It is enough to run LaTeX twice (or three times).

#### Cons

- There is a chance of inconsistencies since you have to format all entries by hand.
- It is time consuming to change the bibliography style, since you have to manually reformat every entry. (Suppose you want the name format `Dower, John W.` instead of `John W. Dower` in all of your entries. You'd have to invert each and every name manually.)
- When you add new entries, you need to make sure to get the sorting order right. This is especially tricky if you want to sort your bibliography in citation order so that in your text the first work you cite is numbered [1], the second [2] and so forth. Every time you move around a few sentences with citations you run the risk of having to check your sort order.
- In case your bibliography entries have context-dependent features like disambiguation letters for works by the same author from the same year (Sigfridsson 2000a and Sigfridsson 2000b), you need to manually calculate those features and keep track of them if anything changes.

For a handful bibliography entries with a straightforward bibliography style writing `thebibliography` manually is an option. But as soon as you plan on citing more works or want to be able to change the style easily or want to avoid inconsistencies other methods are usually better.

### `.bib` files (BibTeX)

`.bib` files are a way to address many of the cons of a manual `thebibliography` by introducing another layer of abstraction and a middle man called BibTeX. `.bib` files contain the relevant bibliographic information of a work you want to cite in a systematic and machine-readable form.

```
@article{sigfridsson,
  author  = {Sigfridsson, Emma and Ryde, Ulf},
  title   = {Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the
             electrostatic potential and moments},
  journal = {Journal of Computational Chemistry},
  year    = 1998,
  volume  = 19,
  number  = 4,
  pages   = {377-395},
  doi     = {10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P},
}
```

Instead of writing `thebibliography` manually you tell LaTeX about the bibliography style you would like to see your bibliography formatted in and BibTeX (a helper program, see [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864)) will produce the `thebibliography` environment for you (in the `.bbl` file), which LaTeX automatically reads and typesets.

Assuming your `.bib` file called `mybibfile.bib` contains the above entry, you could cite it and produce a bibliography in your document called `mydoc.tex` with

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{mybibfile}
\end{document}
```

by running (at least) LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX, LaTeX (more precisely `pdflatex mydoc`, `bibtex mydoc`, `pdflatex mydoc`, `pdflatex mydoc`, assuming `pdflatex` is your preferred flavour of LaTeX) on that file.

### Pros

- All entries are automatically formatted according to a given style. Inconsistencies are less likely.
- Changing the output style is as easy as selecting another `\bibliographystyle`.
- Sorting happens automatically.
- Extra information can be calculated on the fly for you.
- It is much easier to re-use entries from other documents by just copying them over. They way BibTeX works means that you can have `.bib` entries in your `.bib` file that you don't cite. That means that it is possible to have one master `.bib` file for several documents with different bibliographies.

### Cons

- You need an external program (BibTeX) and extra compilation steps (LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX, LaTeX instead of just LaTeX, LaTeX).
- You need an external `.bib` file.
- If you want to modify the format you need to learn to manipulate BibTeX styles (`.bst` files) with their reverse Polish notation.
- You need to learn how to write `.bib` files and use the BibTeX ecosystem.

### `.bib` files (`biblatex`)

There is actually another method that shares the same basic ideas of `.bib` files as the BibTeX approach: `biblatex`. From a user perspective the BibTeX method explained above and `biblatex` are not all that different: You have a `.bib` file, you have a few commands in your `.tex` file to tell LaTeX and its helper which bibliography style you want, you run an external program (with `biblatex` usually Biber instead of BibTeX, though `biblatex` also works with BibTeX as backend). But under the hood the two systems are very different. `biblatex` does not rely on `thebibliography` and completely reimplements all bibliographic and citation features. Its bibliography style programming language is not based on the reverse Polish notation from BibTeX, styles can be programmed directly in LaTeX.

To the intents and purposes of this comparison the pros and cons of `biblatex` and BibTeX vs `thebibliography` are roughly the same. A detailed comparison can be found in [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/35864).

`.bib` files make sense if you have a larger bibliography and if you don't want to have to worry about consistency, formatting details and sorting. I usually recommend to use `.bib` files over manual `thebibliography`. Whether you want to use classical BibTeX or `biblatex` is a different matter (I'm biased towards `biblatex`, but there are reasons to prefer BibTeX over `biblatex`).

---

### `filecontents`

As mentioned above `filecontents` is not really something that can be compared to `thebibliography` and the BibTeX or `biblatex` approach to bibliographies, it is just a way to produce external files from within a `.tex` document. `mydoc.tex` from above would then look like

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{sigfridsson,
  author  = {Sigfridsson, Emma and Ryde, Ulf},
  title   = {Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the
             electrostatic potential and moments},
  journal = {Journal of Computational Chemistry},
  year    = 1998,
  volume  = 19,
  number  = 4,
  pages   = {377-395},
  doi     = {10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

You would run LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX, LaTeX on that file and that would produce a document with a citation and a bibliography. The interesting bit is that the first LaTeX run will produce the `.bib` file `mydoc.bib` that is then used as the bibliography database.

---

### Further reading

This answer was meant as a short comparison between manual `thebibliography` and `.bib` files with BibTeX/`biblatex`. It does not want to be a tutorial or showcase of BibTeX.

There are many tutorials and beginner's guides out there for bibliographies with LaTeX. Some are very good, others not so much.

I think https://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/html/biblio.html and https://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/thesis/html/citations.html are very good places to start for `thebibliography` and BibTeX/`biblatex`.

For `biblatex` there is [biblatex in a nutshell (for beginners)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509/35864).

Comment: Wow thats the longest reply I have ever seen. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Just to make it clear: In your given code is an relevant error (you missed to define the filename the given code should be stored in: `{mybibfile.bib}`), it should be:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{mybibfile.bib}

@article{A1,
  keywords = {articles},
  title={First Paper},
  author={Green},
  journal={Journal 1}, 
  note={based on \cite{C2}},
  year={2014}
}
```

That simply means (check also the documentation of `filecontents` with `texdoc filecontents`) that the following tex code in an mwe (and only in an mwe, for your work you need not to use `filecontents`) has an line like

```
\bibliography{mybibfile}
```

for `bibtex` or

```
\addbibresource{mybibfile.bib}
```

for `biblatex` and biber.

For you you would have two files, one called `mybibfile.bib` (containing the bib entrys you need in your tex document `mwe.tex`):

```
@article{A1,
  keywords = {articles},
  title={First Paper},
  author={Green},
  journal={Journal 1}, 
  note={based on \cite{C2}},
  year={2014}
}
```

In your file `mwe.tex` you use this bib file as showed above. In your text you have then somewhere `\cite{A1}` to reference this bib entry.

Do not write the bibliography by your own with adding

```
\begin{thebibliography}{10}
\bibitem{notes} John W. Dower {\emph{Readings compiled for History 21.479.}} 1991.
\bibitem{impj}  The Japan Reader {\emph{Imperial Japan 1800-1945}} 1973: Random House, N.Y.
\end{thebibliography}
```

into `mwe.tex`. That too much ends with ugly errors you can omit using a bib file.

So the following MWE

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{mybibfile.bib}
@article{A1,
  keywords = {articles},
  title    = {First Paper},
  author   = {Green},
  journal  = {Journal 1}, 
  note     = {based on \cite{C2}},
  year     = {2014},
}
@book{adams,
  title     = {The Restaurant at the End of the Universe},
  author    = {Douglas Adams},
  series    = {The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy},
  publisher = {Pan Macmillan},
  year      = {1980},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\begin{document}

This is text with \cite{A1} and \cite{adams}.

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{mybibfile}

\end{document}
```

is equivalent to the usage in reality of the bib file `mybibfile.bib`

```
@article{A1,
  keywords = {articles},
  title    = {First Paper},
  author   = {Green},
  journal  = {Journal 1}, 
  note     = {based on \cite{C2}},
  year     = {2014},
}
@book{adams,
  title     = {The Restaurant at the End of the Universe},
  author    = {Douglas Adams},
  series    = {The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy},
  publisher = {Pan Macmillan},
  year      = {1980},
}
```

and the tex code in file `mwe.tex` in the same directory:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\begin{document}

This is text with \cite{A1} and \cite{adams}.

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{mybibfile}

\end{document}
```

**Conclusion:**

Please read an introduction into LaTeX and bibtex and using bib files!